# SQL Server index not considered for execution plan

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below index in a table. But while looking into query plan, looks like the index is not being considered for Index-Scan. Could someone please let me know whats is going missing here?

Index :

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Profile_ProfileStatusId_IsVoiceMailDeposit_IsVoiceMailRetrieve] 
   ON [dbo].[Profile] ([ProfileStatusId], [IsVoiceMailDeposit],[IsVoiceMailRetrieve])
      INCLUDE ([Id], [LocationId], [SubscriberId], [PersonId], [PartitionId],[ProfileTypeId], [InternalCallerId], [Extension], [IsPrimary], [IsInDirectory],[IsSuspended], [TnId], [BoblFirstName], [BoblLastName], [BoblEmail],[TnCountryId])
    GO
```

Execution plan:

[image]

This plan is part of a bigger SP with lot other tables. However, if I run the below extracted test query, the index is considered. Its just that when it combines with the stored procedure, it fails to use index.

Test query:

```
select 
    pr.PartitionId, pr.PersonId, pr.InternalCallerId, pr.Extension, pr.TnId, pr.TnCountryId
from 
    [Profile] pr 
left join 
    [Person] pe with (nolock) on pr.PersonId = pe.Id
inner join 
    Partition pt with (nolock) on pr.PartitionId = pt.Id
where 
    --a.IsDeleted = 0 and  
    --(svcA.ServiceClassId in (select ServiceClassId from [service_ServiceClassProfileTypeMapping]) or svcA.ServiceClassId is null)and
    pr.ProfileStatusId = 0 -- only Active
    and 0 = pr.IsVoiceMailDeposit and 0 = pr.IsVoiceMailRetrieve
```

Test query's plan : (note that same predicates are out put list are used)

[image]

Query  :http://pastebin.com/YJbsN4dy

Plan  : http://pastebin.com/7zR5W8ie

View : http://pastebin.com/cdxTSXcs

Comment: That's nice.  Perhaps including the query in the question would help other people understand what is going on.

Comment: Post your SQL Query..

Comment: Seems like you're not using `[ProfileStatusId]`

Comment: @dnoeth ProfileStatusId is in the MainIndex list

Comment: But not in the predicates shown in the exection plan :-)

Comment: Which version of SQL server are you using?... Just to rule it out; has a specific execution plan been pinned? Maybe using Query Store in SQL 2016. Fairly unlikely I think. As already mentioned we really need to see the query.

Comment: Can you post execution plan as xml

Comment: I am trying to figure out a way to upload a bigger file (XML and SQL are more than 3000 chars)

Comment: please post to paste bin and give the link

Comment: Added the paste bin links of plan and query